# Entity Framework: I don't understand the purpose of EntityCollection.Attach and EntityReference.Attach

Tags: entity-framework-4

`ObjectContext.Attach` and `ObjectSet.Attach` are used to attach a detached entity ( which already exists in a DB ) to a context – this way when *ObjectContext.SaveChanges* is called, EF doesn't try to send an insert command for this attached entity

But I don't understand the purpose of `EntityCollection.Attach` and `EntityReference.Attach`. Namely, the two methods can only attach entities that are already managed by `ObjectContext` ( thus they can't be used to attach entities with `EntityState` set to `Added` or `Detached` ).

And since entities managed by `ObjectContext` already have their relationships automatically resolved ( ie their `EntityReference` property returns a parent entity and their `EntityCollection` property contains related child entities ), I fail to understand what exactly would we gain by using `EntityCollection.Attach` or `EntityReference.Attach` to attach a related entity **E1** to a particular entity **E2**, since **E1** was already attached to **E2** automatically by `ObjectContext`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As an example, if you have a customer in the ObjectContext and you want to get that
customer’s reservations, you could call the following:

```
myCust.Reservations.Load()
```

This would load all of the reservations for that customer.
However, if you want to filter those reservations, you can use CreateSourceQuery in-
stead, as shown in the following code:

```
var customer=context.Contacts.OfType<Customer>().First();
var sourceQuery = customer.Reservations.CreateSourceQuery()
                    .Where(r => r.ReservationDate > new DateTime(2008, 1, 1));
customer.Reservations.Attach(sourceQuery);
```

The  query  will  execute  when  the  Attach  method  is  called.  Now  only  the  subset  of reservations for that customer will be retrieved from the database and materialized as
objects.

You can also use CreateSourceQuery to filter on types. In the following code, Attach is
being used with an EntityReference, which will not take IQueryable. Instead, you need
to pass in an object, which you can get using the FirstOrDefault query method. Since
Attach will throw an exception if you attempt to pass in a null, you need to test for null
before calling Attach:

```
var addresses = context.Addresses.Take(5);
foreach (var a in addresses)
{
  var sq = a.ContactReference.CreateSourceQuery()
            .OfType<Customer>().FirstOrDefault();
  if (sq != null)
    a.ContactReference.Attach(sq);
}
```

With this code, only customers will be loaded.

Comment: hi, at my current level of EF programming experience ( which is almost non existing ), I don't find CreateSourceQuery all that useful. Are EntityCollection.Attach and EntityReference.Attach useful in any other situation?